# Simple View Controller Switch in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

This really should work. This is one of the simplest things to achieve in iOS and for some reason it's just not working.

I have two view controllers in my storyboard. One is InitViewController and the other is ViewController, with a storyboard ID of Init and ViewOne respectively. I have a button on InitViewController that is running code to switch the views. The code is running properly but nothing happens despite that fact. Here is the code:

```
-(IBAction)NextPage:(id)sender{
  ViewController *wc = [[ViewController alloc]
                                initWithNibName:@"ViewOne"
                                bundle:nil];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:wc animated:YES];

}
```

I imported ViewController.h, I just don't know why this isn't working.

Comment: Is your initial view controller actually nested inside a `UINavigationController`? That could be one reason a "present" segue works when a manual call to `pushViewController:animated:` does not, as it will fall back to a modal presentation when not nested in a navigation controller.

Comment: Well there is no surprise if it didnt worked. IS the view controller returning the exact view controller with name ViewOne? Where is your view controller ? Is it in a xib or is it in storyboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initWithNibName:` is for view controllers that you create in `.xib` files, not storyboards.  To create a view controller from a storyboard use `-[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]`

```
ViewController *wc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewOne"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:wc animated:YES];
```

Comment: You can also set up a push segue in the storyboard instead of doing the action in code

Comment: The code above doesn't seem to do it either. I even tried [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewOne"]; What could I be missing? I'll try the segue next.

Comment: Okay, the push segue worked, but it's still not ideal. I would prefer to be able to dynamically set a button to go to different areas based on previous user interaction.

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work? Is `wc` nil? or the navigation controller? Are you sure your identifier is set correctly in the storyboard?

Comment: It's not nil, I can even see the title I set for that view in the debug area, but the view just doesn't come up.

Comment: I normally use a menuviewcontroller with ECSlidingViewController to change areas, do I have to add a nagivationController there or import it?

Answer (score 0):

You need a NavigationController - try to log `self.navigationcontroller` and you will see is `null`
In your storyboard add a `UINavigationController` set it as entrypoint, set `InitViewController` as root view controller and then you can use:

```
ViewController *wc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewOne"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:wc animated:YES];
```